# Select limitando consulta, e não exibe as ultimas consultas

Tags: php, html, query, mysqli, while

Neste script, é limitado a exibição de 6 consultas no SELECT na variável $quantidade_pg = 6, utilizei o IF para informar que todas as situações de notícias diferentes de 2 (despublicadas) devem ser exibidas. 
O detalhe é que no meu SELECT, em ordem de criação do mais recente ao mais antigo, o detalhe é que ao limitar 6 notícias, e estiver com a data mais antiga não exibe estas notícias.
Exemplo: Tenho total de 10 notícias, 1 por semana, mas é exibida as últimas 6 notícias na ordem da mais recente a mais antiga, mas ao despublicar 6 notícias, nas semanas do meio, deixando as 2 notícias mais recentes e as 2 últimas notícias, deveriam ser exibidas, mas neste script somente exibe as 2 mais recentes não exibindo as mais antigas. Parecendo que o IF se limita ao SELECT, e acaba entendo que tem 6 consultas.
Procurei pela net para limitar no while ou aldo tipo, ou fazer o INNER JOIN no SELECT.
Alguém poderia me ajudar. 
Tenho esse codigo:

```
        $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
        //Selecionar os noticias a serem apresentado na página da mais recente a antiga
        $result_noticias = "SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY created DESC";

        //Selecionar os noticias a serem apresentado na página
        $resultado_noticias = mysqli_query($conn, $result_noticias);

        //Contar o total de noticias
        $total_noticias = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_noticias);

        //Seta a quantidade de noticias por pagina
        $quantidade_pg = 6;

        //calcular o número de pagina necessárias para apresentar os noticias
        $num_pagina = ceil($total_noticias/$quantidade_pg);

        //Calcular o inicio da visualizacao
        $incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;

        //Selecionar os noticias a serem apresentado na página
        $result_noticias = "SELECT * FROM noticias ORDER BY created DESC limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
        $resultado_noticias = mysqli_query($conn, $result_noticias);
        $total_noticias = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_noticias);
                <?php while($row_noticias = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_noticias)){?>
```

">

- 

...

Mas no meu banco tenho a tabela noticias e a coluna **situacao_noticia_id** *(id1/id2)*.
Possuo a outra tabela **situacao_noticia**, nela as colunas *(id/nome)*, assim
(id1/publicada)-(id2/não publicada).
Gostaria que, quando o ID estiver 2 (não publicado), não exiba a noticia no while.
Está faltando conhecimento da minha parte.

Comment: Se você possui uma chave estrangeira da tabela noticias na tabela situacao_noticia você poderia usar um INNER no query e só retornar o que não tivesse o ID 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente colocar seu article inteiro dentro de um if/else. No if você verifica se o id da noticia é igual a 2, se for, apenas mande continuar, se não, manda executar o bloco else com o article dentro.

Comment: Obrigado @ikaro - isso mesmo.
    <?php if($row_noticias['situacao_noticia_id']=2) { ?>
While....
<?php } else {} ?>

Comment: Magina cara, se a resposta ajudou na solução, marca como certa para que outros vejam e ajudem-os também ;)

Comment: Editando da forma correta.
Criei uma tabela com 2 colunas, tabela=situacao_noticia - coluna id (Auto increment, coluna nome (Publicado/não publicado).

E antes da div <article> inseri um if
 <?php if($row_noticias['situacao_noticia_id']!=2) { ?>
!=(diferente de 2)

após o </article> usar um else {} vazio.

Somente para ajudar no entendimento e corrigindo o primeiro comentário.

Comment: Resolvido de uma forma bem simples, fui pesquisar sobre SELECT e simplesmente removi os seguintes itens:
`$num_pagina = ceil($total_noticias/$quantidade_pg); $incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;`
E removi a variável  _&incio_ do **SELECT**  e adicionei a condição **WHERE**, que é até obvia:
`$result_noticias = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE situacao_noticia_id = 1 ORDER BY created DESC limit $quantidade_pg";`

E removi o IF, não importa da data, sempre exibe os publicado do ID 1 e exibe a quantidade de 6. Obrigado a quem ajudou.